# Is there a way to get security baseline in an applet?

Tags: java, security, applet

With recent changes in applet security and resulting problems (mostly with LiveConnect), I was wondering if there is a way to check current security baseline from within applet code and compare it with current JRE version. This way some action could be taken, like warning the user, instead of just silently failing.

EDIT: To clarify, as of Java 7, Oracle introduced the "Security baseline", which is lowest JRE version considered "secure". Eg. currently it is (i think) 1.7.0_45. So if user has lower JRE installed, applets will start, but some features won't work. In my case, JavaScript to applet calls are blocked. The applet plugin dynamically checks what is current baseline, so I wanted to know if there is a way for an applet to determine this baseline.

Comment: I don't fully understand what you are trying to do: You want to check the applet (somehow) before it is started or do you want to start the applet and then check the Java version it was started with?

Comment: I added clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably referring to the following article: [Security Baseline impacts](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/updated_security_baseline_7u45_impacts).
To my knowledge there is currently no mechanism to detect the current baseline - however there could be a solution:

I wrote an automatic java version checking mechanism for an installer some time ago. You would need that (a) and an understanding of the java baseline versioning mechanism (b). If you have that you start your applet and before doing any liveconnect stuff you check the java version and the current baseline and show some error to the user.

**Regarding (b)**:
If I understand correctly the baseline is determined like this:

> ```
> 7u25 was the previous secure baseline. 7u40 "only" contained bug fixes and did
> not contain security patches -> no update necessary. When 7u45 was released, 
> this critical patch update contained security patches and raised the secure 
> baseline -> Users had to update
> ```

**UPDATE:**
I read about the [new version number scheme](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview/jdk-version-number-scheme-1918258.html). And basically if it is a limited update only (adding new functionality and non-security fixes) the baseline is not raised. For CPU (critical patch updates) the baseline will be raised and the version number will contain odd numbers. -> So you can check whether the patch version is odd or not...
**UPDATE END**

**Regarding (a)**
Three steps are necessary to retrieve the current java version:

1. Download the file: http://javadl-esd.sun.com/update/1.7.0/map-m-1.7.0.xml
2. Parse the file and extract the last https URL: https://javadl-esd-secure.oracle.com/update/1.7.0/au-descriptor-1.7.0_51-b13.xml
3. Theoretically you could extract the version from the url already or you download the xml file behind the url
4. In that 2nd file you'll find the version tag: 1.7.0_51-b13

Comment: Thanks, this might be the way to do it, since no API apparently exists. Also, it seems to me that the last entry in the mapping XML (the first one) could be the current baseline.

Comment: I don't think that since it is just a list of all previous versions, ranging from 1.6.0 to 1.7.0_45. However I can image that the actual update version would still be e.g. 1.7.0_51 even though e.g. 1.7.0_60 appeared...

Comment: You can use this link to get the latest security baselines: http://javadl-esd-secure.oracle.com/update/baseline.version Yet for sandboxed applet (that without all-permissions), Security Manage will block the access to this URL.